# How do I make my C# program start again from the top after every time it finishes

Tags: c#

guys, I'm a beginner at this, after trying to build this calculator I just wanted to learn how to make it start again I tried using a while loop but unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure it out please help thanks.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter a number");
            double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Add an operator");
            string op = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter another number");
            double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if (op == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
            }
            else if (op == "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
            }
            else if (op == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid operator");
            }

        }
     

    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the `Main` function: `while (true) {  <<<put rest of code here>>>  }`

Answer (score 0):

To keep it running, you can add a `while(true)` to wrap your logic code. this will repeatedly execute the block of code. In case there is a condition where you want to exit the loop, you can achieve this via `break`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        
           while (true){

              Console.Write("Enter a number");
              double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

              Console.Write("Add an operator");
              string op = Console.ReadLine();

              Console.Write("Enter another number");
              double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

              if (op == "+")
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
              }
              else if (op == "-")
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
              }
              else if (op == "/")
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
              }
              else if (op == "*")
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
              }
              else
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Invalid operator");
              }

              if (//condition is ok and you want to break out of the loop){
                 break;
              }
         }
      }
```

Comment: It might be good to give him the option to leave this infinite loop.

Comment: I modified my answer @PhilippeB. - thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

If it is console application,
you could do something like this at the end of your app -

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("your_prog_name.exe"); Environment.Exit(0);`

It should terminate previous process and start it again.
Console window won't disappear.

Comment: It would be better to change `"your_prog_name.exe"` to `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`.  Just because when changing the name of the exe-file everything will keep on working.